# AspectJ: Advice not working for array type

Tags: java, aspectj

I defined a pointcut based on a type that's not available when I compile my aspect, but is available when I compile my code.
It works fine when I use a simple type, but not when I use an array.

It looks like the type is being flattened and treated as a non-array type (not being applied for the array type and being applied for the non-array type, exactly the opposite of expected).

#### Simple reproduction

Aspect:

```
public aspect Aspect {
    after() : call(public MaybeMissingClass MaybeMissingClass.*())
    {
        System.out.println("Aspect: MaybeMissingClass 1");
    }
    after() : call(public MaybeMissingClass[] MaybeMissingClass.*())
    {
        System.out.println("Aspect: MaybeMissingClass[] 2");
    }
}
```

Class:

```
// compile all together
//      java -cp aspectjtools.jar;aspectjrt.jar org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main -source 1.6 Aspect.aj Main.java
// compile aspect without concrete class in CP and then compile class
//      java -cp aspectjtools.jar;aspectjrt.jar org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main -source 1.6 Aspect.aj
//      java -cp aspectjtools.jar;aspectjrt.jar org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main -source 1.6 -aspectpath . Main.java

// run
//      java -cp .;aspectjtools.jar;aspectjrt.jar Main

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello from main");
        MaybeMissingClass.f1();
        MaybeMissingClass.f2();
    }
}

class MaybeMissingClass {
    public static MaybeMissingClass f1(){System.out.println("hello from MaybeMissingClass.f1");return null;}
    public static MaybeMissingClass[] f2(){System.out.println("hello from MaybeMissingClass.f2");return null;}
}
```

Output when compiling all together:

```
hello from main
hello from MaybeMissingClass.f1
Aspect: MaybeMissingClass 1
hello from MaybeMissingClass.f2
Aspect: MaybeMissingClass[] 2
```

Output when compiling aspect separately:

```
hello from main
hello from MaybeMissingClass.f1
Aspect: MaybeMissingClass 1
Aspect: MaybeMissingClass[] 2
hello from MaybeMissingClass.f2
```

Can anyone explain this?

**Edit**
Looks like the dimension info is getting lost when calling [`resolveBindingsForMissingType()`](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/V1_9_6/org.aspectj.matcher/src/main/java/org/aspectj/weaver/patterns/WildTypePattern.java#L750) instead of `resolveBindingsForExactType()`.
But it doesn't really make sense. This info is available at aspect-compile-time and at weave-time, so why discard it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I created [AspectJ issue #24](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/24) for you in order to get feedback and hopefully get the issue resolved, if possible. Maybe this is an edge case not covered by tests and nobody ever noticed.